# Cloud Firestore Authentication iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm very new to iOS development (learning as I go) and I'm using Cloud Firestore to authenticate users via email/password. I'm trying to do a simple email & password authentication. I used one of the db rules from documentation and I don't think I have to create collections and documents in the rules. I've already tested my connection to the db so that's not an issue either. The code I have so far is below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let firstName = firstNameText.text,
        let lastName = lastNameText.text,
        let email = emailText.text,
        let password = passwordText.text else { return }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error creating user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = firstName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                }
        })
            guard let userId = authResult?.user else { return }
            Firestore.firestore().collection(USERS_REF).document(userId).setData([
                USERNAME : firstName,
                DATE_CREATED : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                ], completion: { (error) in

                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
            })
        }
    }



}
```

But I get the error:

- Cannot invoke 'setData' with an argument list of type '([String : Any], completion: ((Error?) -> Void)?)'

Is there something I'm not doing? Could someone help with this email/password authentication?

Answer (score 1):

First check how variables are named properly. In swift we use camelCase.

Second you have tried to assign your textField object to your password inside dictionary.

Third you have tried to print and do a segue outside login action.
Consider editing your code:

```
  @IBAction func SMLoginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     print("Login button tapped!")
     guard let emailText = EmailTextField.text, !emailText.isEmpty else { return }
     guard let passwordText = PasswordTextField.text, !passwordText.isEmpty else { return }
     let saveData: [String: Any] = ["email": emailText, "password": passwordText]
     docRef.setData(saveData) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Oh no! Got an error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Data has been saved to Firestore!")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, the projects builds now but it won't login the user. It recognizes the tap (gives "login button tapped" message) but doesn't actually login the user and go to the next segue. Any reason why?

Comment: Try using `db` instead `docRef`

Comment: I've taken a different approach, but not sure about the above error. I changed the user reference to authResult and then this error came up. Any idea how to troubleshoot it? @DionizB